# Filtrar por valor de campo lookup en grid editable D365 UCI

Tags: javascript, api, microsoft, dynamics-crm

Recientemente se me ha presentado un desafío que no sé ya como afrontar.
El problema es el siguiente, en un entorno de dynamics 365 UCI, tengo un grid editable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero conseguir en este grid editable, es que cuando seleccione un formato, y vaya a seleccionar variedad , solo me aparezcan las opciones de variedad que tengan ese formato.
Esa funcionalidad la tengo hecha aquí ( la de obtener las variedades que debería mostrar)

```
    try {  
                var fieldFormato = execContext.getFormContext().getAttribute("formato").getValue();
                var fieldFormatoId = fieldFormato[0].id.replace("{","").replace("}","");  
                var dataGridLookupAttributeName = "variedad";  
                var serverURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();  
                var oDataWebApiUrl = serverURL + "/api/data/v9.2/";  
                var oDataQueryUrl = oDataWebApiUrl + "opportunityproducts?$select=_variedad_value&$filter=_formato_value eq " + fieldFormatoId;  
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
                req.open("GET",encodeURI(oDataQueryUrl), true);  
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");  
                req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");  
                req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");  
                req.onreadystatechange = function () {  
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {  
                        req.onreadystatechange = null;  
                        if (this.status == 200) {  
                            var data = JSON.parse(this.response)  
                            console.log(data);
                                    UpdateLookupFetchXml(execContext, dataGridLookupAttributeName, data);
                                }  
                        else {  
                            var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;  
                            console.log(error.message);  
                        }  
                    }  
                };  
                req.send(null);            
        }  
        catch (err) {  
    }            
}
```

En esta función obtengo el id de las variedades que me interesan, y trato de actualizar el valor del campo variedad con la función `UpdateLookupFetchXml`, esta función hace lo siguiente

```
function UpdateLookupFetchXml(execContext, dataGridLookupAttributeName, data) {
    var formContext = execContext.getFormContext();
    var entityAttribute = formContext.data.entity.attributes.get(dataGridLookupAttributeName);
    
    if (!entityAttribute) {
        return;
    }

    var variedadIds = data.value.map(v => v._variedad_value);

    var filterXml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < variedadIds.length; i++) {
        filterXml += '<value>' + variedadIds[i] + '</value>';
    }

    var fetchXml = '<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical">' +
        '<entity name="opportunityproduct">' +
        '<attribute name="opportunityproductid" />' +
        '<attribute name="_variedad_value" />' +
        '<attribute name="createdon" />' +
        '<filter type="and">' +
        '<condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />' +
        '<condition attribute="_variedad_value" operator="in">' +
        filterXml +
        '</condition>' +
        '</filter>' +
        '</entity>' +
        '</fetch>';



    var lookupObject = null;
    for (var key in entityAttribute) {
        if (key && key.indexOf("lookups") > -1) {
            lookupObject = entityAttribute[key].lookups["." + dataGridLookupAttributeName];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (lookupObject != null) {
        lookupObject.fetchXml = fetchXml;
    }
}
```

El problema es que desde 2018/2019, que contamos con la interfaz unificada, el campo del lookup en el grid editable ya no trae la propiedad "lookup" por lo cuál no lo puedo obtener, y no puedo usar el método .fetchXml para pasarle mi fetch y cambiarle los valores.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto mediante JS?¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Gracias